# Code doesn't work when I reference double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, double-pointer

Why can't I properly store and reference a double pointer?

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _node{
    int nodeNumber;
    int weight;
}* Node;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Node nodeList = calloc(3, sizeof(struct _node));

    // Used for testing
    nodeList->nodeNumber = 9;
    printf("Node Number: %d\n", nodeList->nodeNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

but when I try making the struct a double pointer, and referencing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _node{
        int nodeNumber;
        int weight;
}** Node;



int main(int argc, char **argv){
        Node nodeList = calloc(3, sizeof(struct _node));

        // Used for testing
        nodeList[0]->nodeNumber = 9;
        printf("Node Number: %d\n", nodeList[0]->nodeNumber);

        return 0;
}
```

My program runs for a second then crashes. No error or anything. I thought that referencing the struct with

```
nodeList[0]->nodeNumber = 9;
```

would work but apparently it does not.

Also I would like to note that I know creating a pointer or double pointer directly in the struct is usually considered bad practice but this is part of an assignment and the struct definition was given and must be used "as is". The ultimate goal is to make an array or linked lists. The linked lists part will be find as I think I understand that but this is the problem.

------------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------

I have changed my code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _node{
        int nodeNumber;
        int weight;
}** Node;



int main(int argc, char **argv){
        Node nodeList = malloc(sizeof(struct _node *));

        // Used for testing
        nodeList[0]->nodeNumber = 9;
        printf("Node Number: %d\n", nodeList[0]->nodeNumber);

        return 0;
}
```

but my program is still crashing.

Comment: Change `**` to `*` and it will work. (You declared an array of pointers to the struct.)

Comment: ..and __don't__ typedef pointers! It confuses everybody.

Comment: It doesn't work when I change ** to * . Also, as I stated above, the struct declaration has to be a double pointer.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is part of an assignment and the struct delcaration were given to me and must be used "as-is". Otherwise I wouldn't be using pointers in a typedef at all.

Comment: Please read the tag wiki for "double-pointer" (click on the tag below the question). It's an ambiguous term, which could mean either "pointer to pointer" or `double*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using double pointers, then you should proceed as follows:

```
typedef struct _node{
    int nodeNumber;
    int weight;
} Node;
```

and in your function:

```
    Node **nodelist = malloc(3 * sizeof(Node *));
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        nodelist[i]= calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
```

Note that I don't use pointers in the typedef because it is very confusing. Instead, I declare the `nodelist` as a double pointer.

---

So you professor insists on using a double pointer in the typedef (I suggest you tell your professor to visit stackoverflow.com....). Then proceed as follows:

```
typedef struct _node{
    int nodeNumber;
    int weight;
} **Node;
```

and in your function:

```
    Node nodelist = malloc(3 * sizeof(*nodelist));
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        nodelist[i]= calloc(1,sizeof(*nodelist[i]));
```

Here I don't use the typename but the variable name to determine the size to allocate: the `*nodelist` dereferences the nodelist to a `struct _node *` and the `*nodelist[i]` dereferences that to the actual `struct _node`  (note that the value of `i` is not important here; it is only used to indicate to the compler that an array element is intended).

People prefer it even to use the variable name instead of the type name so when in future the variable would refer to another type, the allocation changes automatically with it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but like I said above I have to use the code "AS-IS". My professor insists on using the double pointers in the typedef declaration. I made a working program another way, but unfortunately I am forced to do it this way. I agree it is very confusing and silly, however I have to adhere to the specs of the assignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul! It works! I tried initializing it myself a different way but it wasn't quite working but it appears your way does! Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

With

```
typedef struct _node{
    int nodeNumber;
    int weight;
}* Node;
```

and

```
Node nodeList = calloc(3, sizeof(struct _node));
```

you make `nodeList` point to the first element of an array of `struct _node` elements.

With

```
typedef struct _node{
        int nodeNumber;
        int weight;
}** Node;
```

then `nodeList` will be a pointer to the first element of an array of ***pointers*** to `struct _node`, but since you use `calloc` all those pointers in the array will be **`NULL`**. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is invalid and leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Furthermore your allocation is wrong since you still allocate memory for three `struct _node` elements instead of `struct _node *` elements.

And as a rule of thumb: Never hide pointers behind type-aliases. It makes code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: @I_am_learning_now `nodeList[0]` is a pointer, but ***where does it point***? Through your use of `calloc` all pointers in the array will be `NULL`.

Comment: Ah ok so I should probably use malloc instead and change my allocation to a pointer is what I'm gathering. I will try that and see if it works

Comment: Ok so when I changed my code, I am still getting the same problem. Check my edit above for new code.

however the program is still crashing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @I_am_learning_now Using `malloc` doesn't change anything, and in fact I would argue making it worse. Now you allocate an array of pointers, but each pointer is *indeterminate*. The pointers in the array will not automatically be initialized and point to nodes. You need to do that yourself. Like `nodeList[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));`.

Comment: Ah k I think that's my problem! Sorry I am not confident with C. I will try initializing them and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question, but in case someone comes across this and is interested how to do this proper:

- Never hide pointers behind typedefs.
- Never use `type**` when you actually want a 2D array. That should only be used for things like a table of strings of variable length, which isn't a 2D array. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for details.
- Always `free()` what you `malloc()`. Sure, the OS will do this for you in most cases. But by calling `free()`, we can expose and detect bugs elsewhere in the code, such as memory leaks, dangling pointers etc etc, which will all manifest themselves as a program crash upon calling `free()`.

Here are examples of proper code, one example with a 1D array and one with a 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int nodeNumber;
  int weight;
} Node;

int main (void)
{
  Node* nodeList = calloc(3, sizeof *nodeList);

  nodeList[0].nodeNumber = 9;
  printf("Node Number: %d\n\n", nodeList->nodeNumber);

  free(nodeList);


  /****************************************************************************/

  const size_t x = 2;
  const size_t y = 3;
  Node (*nodeList2D)[y] = calloc(x, sizeof *nodeList2D);

  int count = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
    {
      nodeList2D[i][j].nodeNumber = count++;
      printf("Node (%d, %d): %d\n", i, j, nodeList2D[i][j].nodeNumber);
    }
  }

  free(nodeList2D);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the `sizeof *nodeList2D` trick when calling malloc/calloc is adaptive to the type used. In case of the 2D array, this will give us the size of one 1D array (same as `3 * sizeof(Node)`), and then we allocate 2 such chunks of memory with calloc.